# Vuetify Menu, edit text field with custom component keypad

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm creating an app with vuetify, and I'm having some issues with v-menu.

I have a text input, and when I click on that it opens up a v-menu. In the menu I have a component I have made, it's a simple keypad from 0-9. And with that keypad I want to change the text input.
I want to have a save button that should save changes made and close the menu. But I cant get it to work.

How can I get this to work with multiple text inputs. I know this might seem like an overcomplicated thing just to edit a text input but the app is going to be run on a larger touch screen and I don't want to open up the big onscreen keyboard just to change a number.

How would you do it?

```
<v-menu bottom :close-on-content-click="false">
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
    <v-text-field
      v-bind="attrs"
      v-on="on"
      v-model="result"
      readonly
    ></v-text-field>
  </template>
  <Calculator :data.sync="result" /> <-------- My keypad component
</v-menu>
```

Keypad componenet

```
    <template>
  <v-card class="widget" @contextmenu.prevent="" color="grey lighten-2" max-width="260" >
    <v-card-text>
      <v-card class="mb-2" elevation="1" min-height="64px" max-height="64px" tile flat color="lighten-grey" >
        <v-card-text>
          <v-text-field dense flat reverse v-model="value" :suffix="suffix" ></v-text-field>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
      <v-row no-gutters class="pb-1">
        <v-col align="center" justify="center">
          <v-btn color="grey lighten-5" @click="click1" tile elevation="1" height="55px" >1</v-btn>
        </v-col>
        <v-col align="center" justify="center">
          <v-btn color="grey lighten-5" @click="click2" tile elevation="1" height="55px" >2</v-btn>
        </v-col>
        <v-col align="center" justify="center">
          <v-btn color="grey lighten-5" @click="click3" tile elevation="1" height="55px" >3</v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row no-gutters class="pb-1">
        <v-col align="center" justify="center">
          <v-btn color="grey lighten-5" @click="click0" tile elevation="1" height="55px" >0</v-btn >
        </v-col>
        <v-col align="center" justify="center">
          <v-btn color="grey lighten-5" @click="clickDecimal" tile elevation="1" height="55px" >.</v-btn >
        </v-col>
        <v-col align="center" justify="center">
          <v-btn color="grey lighten-5" @click="clickClear" tile elevation="1" height="55px" >C</v-btn >
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row no-gutters class="pt-2">
        <v-col align="right">
          <v-btn @click="cancel" tile small>Cancel</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="ml-2 mr-0" @click="onSave" tile small>Save</v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['data', 'suffix'],
  data() {
    return { value: '0', };
  },
  methods: {
    click0() {
      if (this.value.toString().length > 9) return;
      if (this.value === '0') { this.value = ''; }
      this.value = this.value + '0';
    },
    click1() {
      if (this.value.toString().length > 9) return;
      if (this.value === '0') { this.value = ''; }
      this.value = this.value + '1';
    },
    click2() {
      if (this.value.toString().length > 9) return;
      if (this.value === '0') { this.value = ''; }
      this.value = this.value + '2';
    },
    click3() {
      if (this.value.toString().length > 9) return;
      if (this.value === '0') { this.value = ''; }
      this.value = this.value + '3';
    },
    clickClear() {
      this.value = '0';
    },
    clickDecimal() {
      if (this.value.includes('.')) return;
      this.value = this.value + '.';
    },
    onSave() {},
    cancel() {},
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Consider emitting `result` from the child `Calculator` component and set the same from the `parent`.

Comment: Could you share your keypad component? Emiting events to update parent v-text-field like Anees said is the right way. I can make a codesandbox for you.

Comment: I tired using emit, but could't figure out how to do it with multiple text fields.
I can share my component, but its to big for this comment.

Comment: I added to component in my question @cmfc31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your keypad component code. Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-70120821-5uyq4?file=/src/components/Keypad.vue

I simplified the use of your keypad component by removing the inner text field and cancel/save buttons, also optimized the way the numpad is generated, but you can modify it to your taste.

I setup up a watcher for the inside **value** number of the keypad. And whenever it gets updated, emits an event called **"output"** to his parent with the new value.

```js
 watch: {
    ...
    // When inner value gets a new value, emits and event to parent
    value(val) {
      this.$emit('output', val)
    }
  },
```

On the parent side, you receive the new value by setting up the custom event **@output**. The **$event** var contains the data emited from the child component. In this example I just simply update the value of the **v-text-field** of the parent component. But you can also pass this value to a method if you need to validate something or do other things with it.

```html
    <Keypad :input="result" @output="result = $event" />
```

In case you need to update the keypad value from the parent component you can do it usign the prop I defined called **input**. To be able to work properly on the initial load of the page, you need to use the **eager** prop on the **v-menu**. That way, the custom keypad component gets rendered since the beggining.

Comment: Wow, Thank You! I really appreciate that 

I couldn't get the watcher on input to work, I hade to change to this
`input: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(val) {
        this.value = val;
      },
    },`

I also have one more problem, I really need to have a save button as an extra protection. I have no problem setting up the metod for that, but I cant figure out how to close the v-menu.
I can do it with v-model but since there a lot of text inputs that will be alot of methods. Seems like is a better way of doing it, can I pass down the attrs and on somehow?

Comment: Hi, I'm glad to help. I updated the codesandbox to implement the cancel/save functionality. What do you mean about the multiple text inputs?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have a lot of text input in one component, and I couldn't figure out how to use this when opening the v-menu with v-model. But then I figured out, I use a v-for and an array to render all v-menu. It works great!